# Why does internet explorer push my content below the sidebar?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a page which displays just fine, in Firefox and Chrome. However, it has the content pushed past the bottom of the sidebar (as if I had a clear) in Internet Explorer 8 (I haven't tested any other IE versions). Does anyone know how to fix this?

The page is located [here](http://formulator.codingproject.net/content/login)

Thanks,

Lemiant

Comment: Why are you trying to create the site in quirk mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp) for you page. Without it, IE will revert to [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which is essentially IE 5.5's rendering engine.

What you're observing is IE incorrectly computing widths for your elements, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) for a description on how IE 6 and older versions implement width.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that remains a mystery to me, IE thinks the #content element is wider than it should be.
This code did the trick for me:

```
#content {
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-right: 250px;
  width: 550px;
  width: 497px\9;
}
```

This makes all browsers use the width of 550px, and IE (all versions), 497px, which seems to be tha maximum it accepts. Hacky, but it works :D

EDIT: You're missing a !doctype. This might be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm sure that I will use that trick some time.